# I can't upgrade kernel on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1

Tags: server, upgrade, kernel

today I made a mistake and now I don't know how can I fix it.

I updated the kernel using dist-upgrade and I installed Linux 3.13.0-39-generic on my server. I had Linux 3.13.0-37-generic.

The thing is that I ran the following command to remove old kernels, but I did it before to reboot... (my bad)

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

The problem that I have now is that seems that I removed 3.13.0-39 instead of 3.13.0-37. I rebooted the server, and I still have 3.13.0-37, and when I run update & dist-upgrade shows that I have not updates...

I'll appreciate any help as I'm new and I don't have exp!

I get this, if I run dpkg -l | grep linux-image

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic       3.13.0-37.64                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic 3.13.0-37.64                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Everyone: Do not use the code in the question!

It purges an arbitrary amount of packages, on my system it would have purged:

- linux-image-3.14.18
- linux-image-3.16.6
- linux-image-3.17.1
- linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae
- linux-image-686-pae
- linux-libc-dev:i386

... and this includes the kernel I'm running at the moment! Probably the only thing keeping it from removing the running kernel is the "are you 100% really sure" message apt outputs - I saw it once but can't remember the wording...
What the hell is that weird command supposed to do anyway?

#### Actual answer

So you upgraded, which installed a new kernel, then removed that kernel using apt and then rebooted?

No problem then, just install the new kernel again using `apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic` (I imagine you didn't run the lowlatency kernel).

Be sure to also install `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic`.

Comment: Jan, thanks for your reply! I ran apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic and now my server did not reboot :(

Comment: Did the kernel install without errors? Plus, open a new question with the actual error message that prevents you from booting.

Comment: There is no error and there weren't errors during apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic. The server is in a data center. I'm using it via SSH. Now I can boot it using a "recuemode" but I don't know what to do...

Comment: I think that the command that you gave me, didn't install the header for the new kernel. Is that possible? I mean, can I have the header for version 37, and the generic for 39?

Comment: You only need header files to compile stuff against, you don't need them to just use the kernel.

Comment: I think the problem was that I didn't install linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic. I need to figure auto how can Install it using the recue mode...